Visualize Azure PostgresSQL table data
We have data stored in different tables in azure postgresql database. Now, we want to create dashboards/reports for our clients to visualize/analyze this data (preferably in azure). I am new to this so I am not sure how to do this. I have few questions:

Is it possible to do this in any Azure native service (may be power bi embedded but that's costly for our use case, as we just want to create simple dashboards)
I know, we can connect Azure postgreSQL to Power BI and create dashboard/reports there. After that, can we show the dashboards in Azure portal somehow?
Any other suggestions are welcome.

I already created a view in Power BI desktop using Azure PostgreSQL tables but didn't find any way to show it in Azure.


I know, we can connect Azure postgreSQL to Power BI and create dashboard/reports there. After that, can we show the dashboards in Azure portal somehow?

You can display Power BI dashboards in the Azure portal by embedding them in Azure applications such as Azure Synapse Analytics. Go to Synapse studio, Create Power BI linked service for your workspace as follows:

Once your workspaces are linked, you can browse your Power BI datasets, edit/create new Power BI Reports from Synapse Studio.

Click  Develop.


Expand Power BI and the workspace you wish to use.



For more information you can refer to the MS document.
